# Coffee script not working when included in assets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have some coffee script that switches around some css classes when collapsing a list, however it doesn't seem to work when I put it in a separate .js.coffee file in the /assets/javascripts directory however it does work when I include it in the HAML file. The coffee script seems to compile and is included in head of the page but doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

```
  $('#collapseTwo').on 'hidden.bs.collapse', ->
    if $('#collapseOne').hasClass('show')
      $('#collapseOne').addClass('extended')
    $('#collapseOne').removeClass('regular')
    $('#collapseTwo').removeClass('regular')
    $('#collapseTwo').removeClass('extended');

  $('#collapseTwo').on 'show.bs.collapse', ->
    unless $('#collapseOne').hasClass('show')
      $('#collapseTwo').addClass('extended')
    if $('#collapseOne').hasClass('extended')
      $('#collapseOne').removeClass('extended')
      $('#collapseOne').addClass('regular')
      $('#collapseTwo').addClass('regular');

  $('#collapseOne').on 'hidden.bs.collapse', ->
    if $('#collapseTwo').hasClass('show')
      $('#collapseTwo').addClass('extended')
    $('#collapseTwo').removeClass('regular')
    $('#collapseOne').removeClass('regular')
    $('#collapseOne').removeClass('extended');

  $('#collapseOne').on 'show.bs.collapse', ->
    unless $('#collapseTwo').hasClass('show')
      $('#collapseOne').addClass('extended')
    if $('#collapseTwo').hasClass('extended')
      $('#collapseTwo').removeClass('extended')
      $('#collapseOne').addClass('regular')
      $('#collapseTwo').addClass('regular');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `gem 'coffee-rails'` to your gemfile, and run `bundle install`.

And remember to `require` the coffeescript file in the application.js like `//= require moment`.

Add `$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->` as first line in the coffee file.

Comment: Gem is already there and file is required in application.js, I can see the compiled JS version of the file in the sources tab on the page and I can see it's included in the head of the page too.

Comment: try add `$(document).on 'ready page:load', -> `as first line in the coffee file.

Comment: Can confirm that adding that has fixed the issue, thanks. Is this normal?

Comment: yes, it' normal, the javascript functions should run after page ready

Comment: I suppose that makes sense, I swear I've done this a hundred times before but never needed that line. Oh well, thanks again.